# Can I use the Android unlock screen in my app?

Tags: android

Is there any way I can use the system's pattern/PIN unlock screen in my app to gain access to the app? I don't need to know the user's system pattern/PIN, but would like to be able to bring up that visual asset when needed without having to generate my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this library](https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/)! With this, you can implement your own custom lock pattern in your app :D
Also, If your app only targets API 11+, you can use [this other library](https://github.com/nadavfima/GlowPadView/) to implement a glow pad from Jelly Bean.